# Visual Basic - Guardar formulario en txt con formato

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Los contacto para que me puedan ayudar con un inconveniente que tengo en un pequeño formulario que uso con visual basic para leer datos.

Tengo un formulario con dos campos : fila y numero de item
Necesito guardar de la siguiente manera:

```html
<table>
<th>fila</th>
<th>item</th>
<tbody>
<tr><td>f1</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>f1</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>f1</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>f1</td><td>4</td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

La fila(txtfila) se escribe primero y cuando presiono enter se ingresan los numero de item(txtpalet) de esa fila que pueden ser muchos. Cuando termino de insertar los numeros de item para esa fila presiono el boton guardar y  genero un archivo .csv en el equipo.

Esto funciona, pero solo consigo guardar el numero de item :

```
item 
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

No logro guardar otra columna a ese archivo que sea la fila...

Este es mi código :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Dim _stringBuilder As StringBuilder

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtFila.Focus()
        _stringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtPalet_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPalet.KeyPress

        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            _stringBuilder.Append(txtFila.Text)
            _stringBuilder.Append(txtPalet.Text).AppendLine()

            txtPalet.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fecha As String
        Dim hora As String
        Dim archivo As String

        fecha = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")
        hora = Now.ToString("HHmm")
        archivo = "bpt1" + "_" + fecha + "_" + hora + ".csv"

        Dim writer = New StreamWriter(archivo, True)
        writer.Write(_stringBuilder.ToString())
        writer.Flush()
        writer.Close()
        MsgBox("Documento Guardado como : " + archivo)
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtFila_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFila.KeyPress
        Dim valorFila As String

        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            valorFila = txtFila.Text
            If Len(valorFila) >= 2 Then
                txtPalet.Focus()
                txtFila.ReadOnly = True
            Else
                MsgBox("Ingrese una Fila Valida")
                txtFila.Text = ""
                txtFila.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Si me pueden dar el dato de como incluir la nueva columna en el archivo,
tener :

columna 1 (fila)       columna 2 (item)

gracias.

Comment: Esto funciona de milagro. Si pones todo esto _stringBuilder.Append(txtFila.Text)
        _stringBuilder.Append(txtPalet.Text).AppendLine() por cada tecla presionada, vas a tener un string un poquito gigante, ya que por cada tecla, volves a meter todo en el stringbuilder!

Comment: Amigo, alguna sugerencia de como mejorar el codigo?